# Definition of BIBO stability of a nonlinear system

Tags: systems-engineering, stability, nonlinear-control

I am studying an electric motor whose state-space equations are nonlinear.
I am trying to control the system through a closed loop and I would like to verify the BIBO stability.

For linear systems, there is a lot of literature that discusses the BIBO stability, which is defined for instance in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIBO_stability).
**Can  this definition be naturally extended to the nonlinear case?**

Sorry, this maybe is a trivial question but I can't find anything on the web about BIBO stability of nonlinear systems.

Comment: been a while, but I think for nonlinear systems you would use  Lyapunov stability (internal stability) instead, which can be proved by the existence of a Lyapunov function (can be loosely analogous to total energy) which must also be bounded or decreasing. IIRC there's a theorem using the linearization around an equilibrium point also, which might be what you want. But cases with stable limit cycles around an unstable point are the real purpose (useless observation: much of what we think of as stable in approximately linear engineering systems use is really this, if we look closely)

Comment: Ok thanks a lot but what's about the definition of BIBO stability for nonlinear systems?

Comment: the definition of BIBO is the same. ||u(t)|| < B_u  ->  ||y(t)|| < B_y

Comment: Ok thanks a lot so much!

Comment: See Also: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input-to-state_stability